# Macros for copy data from one sheet to another by conditional formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project where in excel there are huge data. Each data have number for rows and columns. I want to move this data by condition to there respective sheets.

**Excel workbook:**

First sheet name is `Shortage Report`, it has all the data that should move to there respective sheet by state wise.

**Example:**

`Shortage Report` column `A` have Cities Name:

```
Mumbai
Bangalore
Hyderabad
Kochi
Chennai
..... so on.
```

and Column `D` have place short name. i.e.

```
Mumbai - MU
Bangalore - BU 
etc.
```

I want to **move data using conditional formula**:

- If column `A = Mumbai` and column `D = MU` then move to sheet `MU`.
- If column `A = Bangalore` and column `D = BU` then move to sheet `BU`.
- If column `A = Chennai` and column `D = CH` then move to sheet `CH`.

Could you please help me to create VB script to move these data in a run to there respective sheets.

It will be great help to me. I am spending almost 3 hours to complete this task.

Comment: Can you show the code you are having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some data like this:

```
    A           B   C  
1   Mumbai      MU  Some1
2   Bangalore   BU  Some2
3   Hyderabad   HY  Some3
4   Kochi       KO  Some4
5   Chennai     CH  Some5
6   Mumbai      MU  Some6
7   Bangalore   BU  Some7
8   Chennai     CH  Some8
9   Hyderabad   HY  Some9
10  Mumbai      MU  Some10
11  Mumbai      MU  Some11
12  Chennai     CH  Some12
13  Mumbai      MU  Some13
14  Bangalore   BU  Some14
15  Hyderabad   HY  Some15
16  Bangalore   BU  Some16
17  Chennai     CH  Some17
18  Bangalore   BU  Some18
19  Kochi       KO  Some19
20  Kochi       KO  Some20
21  Bangalore   BU  Some21
```

On a sheet named `Shortage Report`. Then you can use this code:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim i, Lastrow, j
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set sr = Worksheets("Shortage Report")
    Lastrow = sr.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For j = 1 To Lastrow

        SheetName = sr.Range("B" & j).Value

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next

        If wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing Then
            With ThisWorkbook
                .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).name = SheetName
            End With
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        sr.Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Copy
        i = wb.Sheets(SheetName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wb.Sheets(SheetName).Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    Next j

End Sub
```

To make 5 sheets with data like:

```
    A       B   C  
1   Mumbai  MU  Some1
2   Mumbai  MU  Some6
3   Mumbai  MU  Some10
4   Mumbai  MU  Some11
5   Mumbai  MU  Some13
```

On sheet named `MU`

```
    A           B   C  
1   Bangalore   BU  Some2
2   Bangalore   BU  Some7
3   Bangalore   BU  Some14
4   Bangalore   BU  Some16
5   Bangalore   BU  Some18
6   Bangalore   BU  Some21
```

On sheet named `BU`

etc.